# Media query for all tablets (including "Pro" versions), no laptops

Tags: css

I want to apply some CSS styles when the device is a tablet, including Apple iPad Pro (1366px width) and Microsoft Surface Pro 3 (1440px width) but not when the device is a laptop (1024px minus scrollbar or larger). When I use this code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1440px) {
    /*
        non-smartphone touchscreen optimized styles here
        large buttons, menus with everything visible without :hover etc.
    */
}
```

all styles on large tablets (992px-1440px) are incorrect. I tried many different combinations of and/or, min/max in the media query and the rendering was always wrong on at least one device. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: My best tip is _stop device detection_ and work with viewport width. In addition you could detect whether the unit has touch or not.

Answer (score 0):

Given that tablet resolutions overlap with lot of non-touch devices, just depending on the resolution is not going to work. 
You will need to depend on the user-agent string or rely on feature detection.

You can try [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) or [device.js](https://github.com/matthewhudson/device.js/)

Both of them add classes to your root element so that defining css for various device types becomes trivial. device.js is not getting updated much now, but is easier to get started.